# Parsley.js: real-time validation

Tags: parsley.js

Please pardon the noob question — especially if this one is answered elsewhere.

Is it possible to configure parsley.js to validate BEFORE the form is submitted, as the user is working through the form?

Comment: Hi. This is the very purpose of this library :) To validate directly frontend without having to wait a roundtrip to the server for server-side validation..

Answer (score 5):

Use a Parsley.js trigger with one of the jQuery javascript events, e.g.

```
data-parsley-trigger="focusin focusout"
```

Reference doc: [Parsley UI Classes](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#psly-ui-classes)

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks very much — I'll give that a shot.

Comment: Awesome, Works perfectly!